# JOptionPane Looping

Tags: java, swing, loops, if-statement

I have an issue. My lecturer wants me to make a loop, with an input of JOptionPane and an output of console. How can I use loop for JOptionPane and send an output through console.

Here's my code:

```
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int e_e = 0;
int o_o = 0;

String a1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in 10 integer");

for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++){
    int a = Integer.parseInt(a1);

    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
        e_e += a;
    } else {
        odd++;
        o_o += a;
    }
}

System.out.println("\n\nNumber of even numbers : " + even);
System.out.println("Number of odd numbers : " + odd);
System.out.println("Total of even numbers : " + e_e);
System.out.println("Total of odd numbers : " + o_o);
```

Comment: Well, just put your call to the `JOptionPane` inside a loop... What is your program supposed to do? Then we can give you a clear advice on how to change your specific program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a **DO-WHILE loop** with and an `int[]`, example:

```
int size = 10;
int count = 0;

int[] yourNumbers = new int[size];

do {
    yourNumbers[count] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Your message here."));

    count++;
} while (count < 10);
```

This way you can loop through and grab all the numbers. Then you can use a **FOR-LOOP** to cycle through and print what you need

```
System.out.println("Even Numbers are: ");

for(int i = 0; i < yourNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (yourNumbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(yourNumbers[i]);
    } 
}

System.out.println("Odd Numbers are: ");

for(int i = 0; i < yourNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (yourNumbers[i] % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(yourNumbers[i]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see the advantage of first collecting all values and after that again iterating them to process them. But yeah, also works. Of course its nice to know how one can store values in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that you only ask the user **one time** to input a number but you actually seem to want **10 values**. So you parse ten times the same value.

The solution is simple, put the **dialog inside the loop** (only changed the lines with comments):

```
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int e_e = 0;
int o_o = 0;

// No return type, just a message
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type in 10 integer");

for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
    // Dialog inside the loop, asking to
    // input a number in every iteration
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in "
        + (counter + 1) + ". value");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(value);

    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
        e_e += a;
    } else {
        odd++;
        o_o += a;
    }
}

System.out.println("\n\nNumber of even numbers : " + even);
System.out.println("Number of odd numbers : " + odd);
System.out.println("Total of even numbers : " + e_e);
System.out.println("Total of odd numbers : " + o_o);
```

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it.